# inspect filter output in minibuffer or a new buffer

Tags: external-command

Would like to send a line to an external programme and inspect output in the minibuffer or a new buffer.

Don't want the output to replace original text. How to do this?

In gnu emacs there's `M-|` (shell-command-on-region) which will use the either minibuffer or a dedicated "command output" buffer , determined by output length .

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to send the current line, you can do it this way:

```
yy                 " Yank the current line
:new               " Split open a new buffer/window
Vp                 " Paste, replacing the empty line
:%!<command>       " Process buffer with your command
```

I don't know if there is a shorter way.

---

**Update:**

Let's combine this, and Matt Boehm's suggestion, into a mapping for you:

```
nnoremap <Leader><Bar> "zyy:new<CR>:set buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipeout noswapfile<CR>V"zp:redraw<CR>:%!
```

Put that in your ~/.vimrc and now you can just hit <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> when you want to use it.

I took the liberty of changing Matt's `bufhidden=hide` to `bufhidden=wipeout` which will will make the scratch buffer *very* temporary.  Now it will automatically destroy itself if you close the newly split window (for example with <kbd>Ctrl-W C</kbd>).  But beware: it will also **discard any unsaved changes**.  Choose whichever behaviour you prefer.

We use the 'z' register in this mapping to avoid clobbering the default yank register, which might have something useful in it.

The `:redraw` helps to show what is going on but is entirely optional.  Without it, you won't see the split window until you have executed (or cancelled) the external command.

Comment: This is a very sensible solution, I like it.

Comment: Note that if this new buffer is meant to be temporary, you may want to make it a scratch buffer by doing `setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile`. Among other things, this lets you quit vim without saving/deleting that buffer. If you do this regularly, I'd suggest making a keyboard shortcut or getting one of the "scratch" plugins.